# Passing special characters in a url for drill through SSRS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to pass the parameter value to a drill through report in SSSRS. The value i have to pass is a field that i get using MDX and the value is like [F&B]. While i tried to pass the value as usual, it showed an error. Then i could realize that the issue is with the special character "&". I tried replacing it with %26 also. It worked fine when i directly pasted the url in the browser but failed when i implemented it in the Action Expresion.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you URLEncode your parameters.

I believe the ASP function is `Server.URLEncode`

`[` and `]` will probably get encoded as well.